# Can I store a surfboard at Tokyo airport?

Tags: luggage, airports, tokyo

We are traveling from Bali back to the. US with a short stop in Kyoto and Tokyo. Is there somewhere to store 2 surfboards at the Tokyo airport?

Comment: Which Tokyo airport - Narita or Haneda?

Answer (score 1):

Narita has [several Baggage storage](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_06.html) services. Since they define a normal luggage as "medium" size, I would assume that they are able to store larger items, too.

Haneda Airport also has [several places](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/delivery.html#temporary), and indicate over 300cm as "large" size.

Comment: We're assuming it's not Haneda?

Comment: @MarkMayo added Haneda info

Answer (score 0):

I checked the links that uncovery provided and the limitation of baggage for "GPA" at the checked services is "1 linear meter" in size in any direction. Another [site](https://www.americanexpress.com/japan/personal/benefits/travel/airport/delivery.shtml) with different information notes that they only store up to 1.2 meters. So unless you have really short boards, you can't store them.

But if this [link](http://www.visa-news.jp/gold/images/airport/coat_keeping_price.pdf) is to be believed, JAL-ABC does allow surfboards (no dimensional limit noted for Narita; under 2m for Haneda). The only problem is that I can't verify this as the links to JAL-ABC are broken from Narita's website. They might have gone out of business.

So the answer is a very conditional "maybe" -- and you should have a plan B in case you can't find any. Plan B might involve shipping your board from Narita to Kyoto, then posting it immediately back to Narita.