# Can I have my friend check my bag and have it dropped off at their layover airport so I can pick it up?

Tags: luggage, layovers, nrt

I have been traveling around since October and am now in New Zealand.  My last stop before heading home is Japan, with the intention of going snowboarding.  However, I did not bring all my gear around for the last few months.  My friend has a short layover in Narita airport in a few days.

The scenario I'm hoping for is she brings my gear from NY with her and has it left in Narita.  I then (perhaps with a copy of the bag tag) pick up the bag in Japan when I arrive.

Is this feasible?  (Without her leaving the gate area)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly sure that would be impossible in transit, but feasible if she can leave the transit area. How long is your friend's layover? Will she have the time and if necessary the visa to pass through Japanese immigration and back?

Answer (score 4):

It would be a big hassle. There are some [temporary bag storage facilities in Narita](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/can-i-store-a-surfboard-at-tokyo-airport/36684#36684) but they all require you to exit the sterile transit area. She would need to have a visa (or visa waiver) as well as pick up the checked luggage, which most likely was checked right through.

Answer (score 3):

If your friend is American (or other no-visa-needed country) and the layover is a reasonable time (more than a couple of hours) then she will have no problems clearing immigration and customs. It takes about an hour, most of that time is waiting in line and for the bags. Unlike Amerika, Narita has baggage storage in the airport, your bag (officially hers for now) can be placed there. She can email the scan of the receipt to you. About 3 hours start to finish, lets say she needs 4 hours total between flights.

At checkin in New York she will have to get your bag tagged to Narita and not the final destination. Just tell the airport the truth - it's gifts for someone in Japan, you will give it to them during your layover.

Comment: Note that many airlines will *not* allow you to "short-check" your bags to a transit point. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/can-i-pick-up-my-luggage-between-flights-with-the-same-company